# Asynchronous celery task is blocking main application (maybe)

Tags: django, nginx, celery, varnish

I have a django application running behind varnish and nginx.
There is a periodic task running every two minutes, accessing a locally running jsonrpc daemon and updating a django model with the result.
Sometimes the django app is not responding, ending up in an nginx gateway failed message. Looking through the logs it seems that when this happens the backend task accessing the jsonrpc daemon is also timing out.

The task itself is pretty simple: A value is requested from jsonrpc daemon and saved in a django model, either updating an existing entry or creating a new one. I don't think that any database deadlock is involved here.

I am a bit lost in how to track this down. To start, I don't know if the timeout of the task is causing the overall site timeout OR if some other problem is causing BOTH timeouts. After all, a timout in the asynchronous task should not have any influence on the website response?